# How to integrate ReactJS with expressJS

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs

First, I'm very new in ReactJS. I've done simple reactjs project based on following link. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm and I can run and test perfectly by running "`npm start`". But when I'm trying to integrate with expressJs as edit/developed as follow coding, I cannot render at all.

Package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

var isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
var port = isProduction ? process.env.PORT : 3000;
var publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '/');

// We point to our static assets
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
console.log(publicPath)

// And run the server
app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server running on port ' + port);
});
```

Whenever I render as "`npm start`", encounter as follow.

> Cannot GET /

Answer (score 0):

Create an api with in express js that serves the `index.html` page for you as

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(dirname + "index.html");
})
```

In this case you will be able to render you page.

Answer (score 0):

What @Shubham Khatri mentioned is right but there will be one problem. If you have any routes defined in your React application i.e. `http://appDomain.com/products` or `http://appDomain.com/blog` or `http://appDomain.com/articles` that will not work.

The reason is, that you have not defined any route handlers in your Express application for those *(as what you have done for root `/`)*.

If you are willing to run a React application with Express as backend server then you may need to run Express application on separate port i.e. *7070*.

And you React application can run separately on a separate port i.e. *8080*. The React application can further communicate with Express defined Routes, Urls as API end-points to fetch data.

For any further details/discussion please refer to this post: 
[ReactJS, ExpressJS different application Architectures & Modeling and Deployments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506971/reactjs-expressjs-different-application-architectures-modeling-and-deployment)