# ReactJS, ExpressJS different application Architectures & Modeling and Deployments

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, self-hosting

I have gone through different blog articles to find out how a full-fledged application can be modeled and developed with React,Redux (working on front-end) with API end-points communicating with an ExpressJS server.

To my knowledge, we need to have:

> a). One `expressJS` application developed with all possible end-points (available for an API access). This application should be running on a port e.g. *7070*. This server side application will be communicating with the database.
>   b). Develop a `React`, `Redux` based application for front-end and run this application on a different port e.g. *8080* using `webpack`, `gulp` or `grunt` server.

**I am sure this is not the only model.** Or, maybe my concept is little weak. But this post will clarify concepts globally to all Frontend+fullstack developers. Please write your recommendations and expert opinions on followings:

1. Is my defined model right?
2. Is there a way, or possible to use ExpressJS application to throw a ReactJS application as one-page application *(which process and render all defined React routes on client side)*.

   `/* a reference example of using root route handler in Express to throw an 
       index file (which includes bundle.js react application), this works okay, 
       but can not handle or render React Routes on client side; and instead 
       if a menu link clicked that sends request to Express but Express 
       application file only had '/' route to handle.
   */`

   `app.get("/", function(req, res){
       res.sendFile(dirname + "index.html");   // but this is not viable
   })`
3. If point#2 is possible then our application can run on same port right? And our application can also use Express routes as an API end-points. But I'm sure that will not be the recommended way or even possible; unless we do the server side rendering of React *(in our server side ExpressJS application)*.

### Deployment

**Scenario:** React+Redux+Express+DB (mongoDb, Redis, MySql or Postgres etc.) *Full Stack application*

1. **Online/Cloud Hosting**
   Normally we are hosting our application on any 3rd party server (or cloud server). The normal shared hosting does not work unless they have NodeJS server. Most common are: *Heroku, AWS, RedHat OpenShift, Nodejitsu, Microsoft Azure, Modulus, Firebase, etc.*
   In this case most of the server side things are easy to setup and headache free.
2. **Local Network (Internal Company/Corporate Server) Hosting**
   i). Linux Bases server (any version) + SSL installed + Required DB Installation + NodeJS installation + Dedicated IP

   ii). Windows Bases Server + SSL installed + Required DB Installation + NodeJS installation + Dedicated IP

Can anyone elaborate more on the internal server hosting setup procedure with all security measures in more details? I really do not know what each step that should be taken would be.

It will also be helpful if any technical person could write about application modeling as well. This will help everyone.

Note: *The answers should be short in the question context (not in the question subject line context, which is quite broad). Any reference or links will be good to make answer quite short.*

Comment: I typically run the entire application from one server, both for development and production. In development I use `express` with the `webpack-dev-middleware` and then simply use `express` for production. I use middlewares for app proxies, historyFallback, and security. That being said, I am not hosting an API from that application as out service tier is Web API 2.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it is too broad. There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. You should make separate questions (e.g. for points #2 (and #3 could maybe accompany that).

Comment: The answer should be in the question context and not in the subject line context (which obviously will go broad). Any links can be helpful as well instead of elaborating here.